# Show loader after click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is possible to show a loading bar when i click on link?

Example:

I click on `h ref` and i need to wait 5/8 second before the download start, is possibile detect when start and stop the page load?

the `a href` starts a download, but does not change the page.

Answer (score 0):

Nope it's not possible. The statements are executed line by line so even if you have a loader that comes up after clicking a link it'll disappear immediately. 
Your code will be something like this

```
Function clickLink(){
      ShowLoader();
      Download();
      HideLoader();
}
```

If the Download function takes long... Your page will just hang. Then hideLoader will be called immediately. 
The only way for it to work is to make a request which will then wait for a response. 
You can then hide the loader whenever the response is received